# how to fix "the development server returned response error code: 500" this error in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

```js
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
};    
  render() {
    return (
      
      <View  style={{flex: 0,width: 360, height: 700, backgroundColor: 'skyblue', alignContent: 'center'}}>
      <View  style={{flex: 0.2, alignItems: 'center'}}>   
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column',flex: 0.5,alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>             
         <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly' }}>

</View>
 </View>   
         
        <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-evenly' }}>
        <Button 
          title="signup"
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.reset({
              index: 0,
              actions: [
                NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Details' })
              ],
            }))
          }}
        />
       
</View>       
      </View>      
      
    ); 
  }  
}
```

```js
export default class firstpage extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
    
      <View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center'}}>
              <ImageBackground source={require('./abstract-old-grunge-stone-textures_1203-11355.jpg')}
              style={{width: 400, height: 400}}             
           />
        <Text>HOME PAGE</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
  
};
```

```js
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  
  Home: {
    screen: 'HomeScreen',
  },
  detail: {
    screen: 'firstpage',
  },
  Sumbitpage: {
    screen: 'HomeScreen',
  },
  
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
});
export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQqU7.jpg)suggest a solution for this development error,this type error cause my project so much.i can't understand why this error will appear simultaneously. i'll do some many steps,methods for solve this error. any one of you help me to fix this error.

Comment: Please add some screen shots or sample code related to the problem

Comment: According to your error image, it said **Identifier Text has already been declared**, please could you try to check if you have imported or declared identifier Text 2 times.?